# Set UILabel length according to NSString size in pixel : Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ipad, nsstring, uilabel

In my iPad app I am showing scrolling `UILabel` with text that will be fetched from the web service and the text size of the same need to be set Dynamic. My problem is that I will have to set the width of the `UILabel` according to the length of the text to be fetched from the web service.

[I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422742/how-to-know-the-length-of-nsstring-that-fits-a-uilabel-with-fixed-size) [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947970/dynamic-calculation-of-uilabel-width-in-uitableviewcell) [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174007/how-to-calculate-uilabel-height-dynamically) [all](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2014858?start=0&tstart=0) or [most](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/38333-sizing-uilabel-according-string-length.html) of [the](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/64758-scaling-text-fit-view.html) solutions possible but in vain.

Say if the `NSString` where I am storing the string fetched from the server is with 300 characters,it shows 2270 as width using the following code.

```
CGFloat width =  [ScrollingLabel.text sizeWithFont:ScrollingLabel.font].width;

ScrollingLabel.frame = CGRectMake(1024,720,width,45);
```

But then also I am not getting half of the string in the app.

Comment: Your code works fine here. Could it be that you resize the label elsewhere, e.g. with autoresizing masks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could get the solution of my problem just by multiplying the width with 2 that was been resulting with the code :

```
CGFloat width =  [ScrollingLabel.text sizeWithFont:ScrollingLabel.font].width;

ScrollingLabel.frame = CGRectMake(1024,720,width,45);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the best way to accomplish this is to write a category of UILabel and add the method:

```
- (CGFloat)expectedWidth
{
    CGSize size = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font
                        constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(FLT_MAX,self.bounds.size.height)
                            lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode];

     return size.width;
}
```