# Truncate part of text in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uilabel, text-formatting

My requirement is that I need to display text in label in such a way that if the length of text is too big to accommodate in one line, i need to truncate it at the end in such a way that only the last few characters(usually a number b/w 1-1000 so text length may vary.)  are visible and the text before it is truncated with "...".

So the text will look something like "abcdefgijk...10"

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Try this label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;

Comment: I cannot use middle truncation because i need to display only the last few character as "abcdefgijk...10". But NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle will give something like "abcde...lmn10"

Comment: I think this post will help [Truncate UILabel text before 5 character of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874148/truncate-uilabel-text-before-5-character-of-string/51926596)

Answer (score 16):

```
UILabel *contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,100, 150, 30)];
contentLabel.text = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz10";
contentLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
```

Add this label to your display. You should get a output something like this

```
abcdefghijklmnopq...10
```

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4:**

In case someone runs into this issue like i did,

you need to set your `label.numberOfLines = 1`

if you have it set to 0 it will truncate at a space.

so your code should look like

```
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
```

Answer (score 5):

For everyone looking for more recent solution, swift 3 :

```
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
```

`UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation` is deprecated from iOS 6.0.

Comment: Is it Co-incident that Krishna - Balram is together. Well thanks for Answer and Correction

Answer (score 1):

**In Storyboard**

1. Select the Label which you want to truncate the characters.
2. Choose Attributes Inspector.
3. Under Label attributes. You can find **Line Break**

[image]

Done.

Answer (score 0):

there are many methods in NSString class use -length and then use any of these

```
– substringFromIndex:
– substringWithRange:
– substringToIndex:
```

create a temporary string using NSString stringwithFormat, put your desired charecters you get from substringTo index and "....." then your numbers from string by substringFromIndex.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can start with finding the length of characters that can be placed in a line, say 'n' characters. You can take help of this link to determine 'n' [How to know if NSString fits in UILabel or not and index of the last string which fits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155787/how-to-know-if-nsstring-fits-in-uilabel-or-not-and-index-of-the-last-string-whic?rq=1). Next, find the length of the string. If it exceeds n, then extract the last two characters. Ex

```
NSString * fooString = @"a very long string";
NSString * s2 = [fooString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([fooString length]-3, 2)];
NSString * s1 = [fooString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0 , n-5)];
NSString * newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...%@",s1,s2];
```

Comment: What do you mean by `n` here ?
is that `n =  [fooString length]` ?

Comment: no, here n is the maximum characters that can come in that line

Answer (score -1):

We have different Line Break modes for UILabel like

**Truncate Head,
Truncate Middle,
Truncate Tail**

In Xib you can set the Line Break mode what ever you want

Comment: Yes, we are. But they do not give us full control on the exact '...' place.

Answer (score -1):

If you using XIB file..

select --> UILable and 
select --> Attribute inspector tag and change into Line Breaks-->Truncate tail

simply way to truncate characters...

Answer (score -1):

Here is how to use it, `NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle`

```
UILabel *temp = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,75, 100, 50)];
[temp setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
temp.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
temp.text = @"HelloBoss997";
```

Output : 
    `Hello...s997`