# Truncate UILabel text before 5 character of string

Tags: ios, swift, string, uilabel, swift4.2

Is it possible to truncate the UILabel text before 5 character of string in autolayout based on the screen size and different device orientation ex.

> **Test test test test test test...*1234**

I know there are several `lineBreakMode` possible for `UILabel` like `.byTruncatingTail, .byTruncatingMiddle etc.` but nothing is working for my case. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, find your string and calculate position of 5 character before. And add "\n" at that index. May be its help you

Answer (score 1):

Appreciate every once answers and comments above!

So finally I am able to finish it, which is working great in all devices of `iPhone` and `iPad` in `landscape` and `portrait` mode also `split mode` in iPad too!

So i would like to share my implementation here:

**Step1:** Create a TitleView.xib file.

**Step2:** Took Two Label's `Name Label` and `Number Label`.

**Step3:** Given the following constraints to both the labels:

- **Name Label Constraints:**

[image]

- **Name Label Line Break : Truncate Tail:**

[image]

- **Number Label Constraints:**

[image]

**Step4:**
Then load the xib in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let titleView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TitleView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! TitleView
        self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you're asking pretty elegantly by juggling string indexes. If you're planning to do this in a few places in your code, consider creating an `extension` on `String`, to make it easier to reuse. Also consider using an ellipsis (`…`) instead of just three periods.

```swift
extension String {
        
    func truncated(after count: Int, suffix: String = ) -> String {
        guard count < self.count else {
            return self
        }
        
        let truncateAfter = index(startIndex, offsetBy: count)
        return String(self[startIndex..<truncateAfter]) + suffix
    }
}
```

Comment: index(startIndex, offsetBy: count) throws error if total character count is less than count value. Just add a guard statement before first line -
guard self.count >= count else { return self}
let truncateAfter = index(startIndex, offsetBy: count)

Comment: @DebashishDas thanks for the catch - looks like that API changed since I wrote this. I have incorporated your feedback.