# Truncate middle of String and replace it - Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a string like this:

```
0x829bd824b016326a401d083b33d092293333a830
```

I want to leave the first 6 characters and leave the last 4:

```
0x829b...a830
```

How can I do so? I saw on the Apple docs the option `.firstIndex(of: "-")` but that would be for removing a specific character, so it doesn't apply.

Comment: Are you trying to show this in a label or something? In that case you can just let `UILabel` do the work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417767/truncate-part-of-text-in-uilabel

Comment: @aheze I'll be showing it in a SwiftUI view, very likely in a Text("") or label yes, I checked the link you provided but it doesn't seem to apply. The only similar option there is to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle` but that's just letting it do it for me, I'd like more specific, like leaving the last 4 and some digits at front

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you can use `drop`, like this:

```
let stringTest: String = "0x829bd824b016326a401d083b33d092293333a830"
    
print(stringTest.replacingOccurrences(of: stringTest.dropFirst(6).dropLast(4), with: "...")) 

// It will print: 0x829b...a830
```

---

Here **extension**:

```
extension String {
    
    func replacingRange(indexFromStart: Int, indexFromEnd: Int, replacing: String = "") -> Self {
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: self.dropFirst(indexFromStart).dropLast(indexFromEnd), with: replacing)
    }
    
    func replacingRange2(indexFromStart: Int, indexFromEnd: Int, replacing: String = "") -> Self {
        return String(self.prefix(indexFromStart)) + replacing + String(self.suffix(indexFromEnd))
    }

}
```

use case:

```
print(stringTest.replacingRange(indexFromStart: 6, indexFromEnd: 4, replacing: "..."))
```

---

The **Master** Extension from [Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus):

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    
    func replacing<S: StringProtocol>(indexFromStart: Int, indexFromEnd: Int, with string: S = "") -> Self {
        
        Self.init(replacingOccurrences(of: dropFirst(indexFromStart).dropLast(indexFromEnd), with: string))
        
    }
    
    
    func replacing2<S: StringProtocol>(indexFromStart: Int, indexFromEnd: Int, with string: S = "") -> Self {

        Self.init(self.prefix(indexFromStart) + Self(string) + self.suffix(indexFromEnd))
        
    }
    
    func replacing3<S: StringProtocol>(indexFromStart: Int, indexFromEnd: Int, with string: S = "") -> Self {

        Self.init(self.prefix(indexFromStart) + string[...] + self.suffix(indexFromEnd))
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: no no, I'm trying to keep those, not drop them lol and put some dots `...` in the middle

Comment: @Arturo you can also just do `str.prefix(6) + "..." + str.suffix(4)`. Just make sure the string has enough characters.

Comment: Adding on to @LeoDabus if there's not enough (`let str = "asd"`), the result will be `asd...asd`

Comment: @aheze that would result in the same string `asd`. It would be the same as replacing an empty string with something else.

Comment: @aheze I said to make sure there is enough characters

Comment: @Arturo: I add the extension also.

Comment: @swiftPunk as an extension you should extend `StringProtocol` and constrain `Self` to `RangeReplaceableProtocol`. Make the method generic with one generic type to target and another to the replacement string.

Comment: @LeoDabus: ok, I am going implement!  thanks

Comment: @swiftPunk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string/58436623#58436623 remove the mutating keyword and return Self

Comment: @swiftPunk better to simply use a `ClosedRange<Int>` and name it `replacingRange` or maybe `replacingSubrange`

Comment: @LeoDabus: please edit my answer in case if it is not finished, I am done with editing.

Comment: @swiftPunk I just realized a range wouldn't work because the size of the string is unpredictable

Comment: @LeoDabus: I did not planed to catch miss usage of the extension. You know what I mean, I am thinking that developer knows the limits of extension.  But we can work on what you said. why not.

Comment: @swiftPunk the generic method would look like this `extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {` `func replacing<S: StringProtocol>(indexFromStart: Int, indexFromEnd: Int, with string: S = "") -> Self {` `.init(replacingOccurrences(of: dropFirst(indexFromStart).dropLast(indexFromEnd), with: string))` `}` `}`

Comment: @LeoDabus: what is this init() you are using?

Comment: This is required to return `Self`. If you would like to return `String` you can remove it.

Comment: It means if you apply this method on a `SubSequence` it will return a `SubSequence`, in this case a `Substring`. Try `let stringTest = "0x829bd824b016326a401d083b33d092293333a830...".dropLast(3)` `let test = stringTest.replacing(indexFromStart: 6, indexFromEnd: 4, with: "...")`

Comment: @swiftPunk you can use `Self(`, `.init(` or `Self.init`. I like using `.init(`. Swift is a type inferred language so it will work for any type if it doesn't return an optional. When we are returning the type that conform to that protocol we return `Self`

Comment: @LeoDabus: I personally like the `replacing2`

Comment: @swiftPunk yes me too. It is native Swift and probably faster. Note that you can also do `string[...]` instead of `Self(string)`. `.init(prefix(indexFromStart) + string[...] + suffix(indexFromEnd))`

Comment: @LeoDabus: I made it as `replacing3`, for all who followed until here. to be able seeing the development of code.

Comment: @swiftPunk this is called [`UnboundedRange_`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unboundedrange-qf8)

Comment: @LeoDabus: what? you mean about [...] ?  UnboundedRange = [...] ? that was new for me, I must study it in first time I got free time.