# How to get visible text as a string on a UILabel in iOS?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a UILabel with multiple line text. Label text is getting trimmed after 3 lines. I want to know what text is visible in that line. So that after that I can add Read More in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the range of visible text in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311256/calculate-the-range-of-visible-text-in-uilabel)

Comment: iOS 11 Word Wrap makes this way harder. If you used CATextLayer or UITextView to show your text I could probably help but I am not getting anywhere near UILabel and IOS 11 word wrap

Comment: @Smartcat only reason it is not a duplicate is that the answer would not take into account iOS 11 Word Wrap changes to UILabel

Comment: @agibson007 Ok then how about this as a [duplicate SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113461/decrease-the-width-of-the-last-line-in-multiline-uilabel)?

Answer (score 1):

Amazingly, this seems to be difficult. One solution that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11158418/1987726) is to determine which part of the string is displayed in which line. So it should be do-able in a label with not too many lines, although it is everything but elegant...