# Is there are way to determine text end coordinates in UILabel? (not label frame rect)

Tags: ios, uikit, uilabel, uitextview, textkit

I need place some UIView right after text ends with some conditions:

If there are enough space from text end to the right edge of container, place view right after.
If there are no room - place view above.
The problem is - it should work for second line as well.

Here is illustration:
[image: UILabel ends]

I know there are API to get frame of formatted text in UILabel, which kind of work for single line. 
I also know about exclusion path, but it will work only if attached view will be aligned right, but i need it to be placed right after text ends.

Do you know API of TextKit or some trick to achieve this goal?

Possible way to solve this i though is to get the text range from second line and then calculate frame of UILabel for that single line, but i can not find is there are interface to do that.

The whole question is:
How to get width (frame) of the text on the second line of UILabel/UITextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found something for you. please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11158418/2329948). it may help you.

this answer has an algorithm that returns the length of `NSString` that can fit into the `UILabel`. and using that you can find the text of the first line.

After that, you can easily find the actual size of the second line based on the remaining text.